# conditions of "and" and "no" within brackets

Tags: java, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

Why

```
while(!s1.isEmpty() && !s2.isEmpty())
```

and

```
while(!(s1.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()))
```

aren't the same?

Because when I did !(x&y) eclipse gave me an error.
http://pastebin.com/8zBK1jQv

error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) may interest you

Comment: Also, if you have an error, you should always show us the exact error message!

Comment: Also, `&` is different from `&&`. `&` evaluates the first, then evaluates the second, then ANDs the results. `&&` evaluates the first, then it will evaluate the second (and will AND them) only if the first result is `false`.

Comment: The `NullPointerException` also telly you the line number. Can you show us the line in which the error occurs? Also the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: The null pointer happen because the conditions are not equivalent and thus, when using the second, you try to pop out something that does not exist.

Comment: If the NullPointerException is occurring at that line, then clearly s1 is empty and s2 is null.

Answer (score 8):

This is one of [De Morgan's Law's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), fundamental to Boolean algebra:

```
(NOT A) AND (NOT B) == NOT (A OR B)
```

and its converse:

```
(NOT A) OR (NOT B) == NOT (A AND B)
```

i.e, to fix your second version, you must replace the `&&` with `||`.

Comment: But if I do "NOT (A AND B)" eclipse give me an error:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: @NitzanBatat i.e. you should be doing `NOT (A **OR** B)`

Answer (score 2):

Compile the truth tables, and see for yourself:

```
while(!s1.isEmpty() && !s2.isEmpty()):

false, false -> true
false, true  -> false
true,  false -> false
true,  true  -> false

while(!(s1.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty())):

false, false -> true
false, true  -> true
true,  false -> true
true,  true  -> false
```

As you can see from the above, the two conditions have very different meaning.

Also, since `&&` short-circuits, they are different with regards to whether `s2.isEmpty()` is evaluated. The first statement evaluates it iff `s1.isEmpty() == false`, whereas the second evaluates it iff `s1.isEmpty() == true`). If `s2` happens to be `null`, this could determine whether you get a `NullPointerException` or not.

Comment: error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
when using (!(s1.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()))

Answer (score 2):

Check this table (lets say 1=true, 0=false)

```
A|B| !A | !B | !A and !B | A and B |  not(A and B)
-+-+----+----+-----------+---------+---------------
0|0|  1 |  1 |    [1]    |    0    |      [1]
0|1|  1 |  0 |    [0]    |    0    |      [1]   <- (!A and !B)  !=  not(A and B)
1|0|  0 |  1 |    [0]    |    0    |      [1]   <- (!A and !B)  !=  not(A and B)
1|1|  0 |  0 |    [0]    |    1    |      [0]
```

As you see for `A=1, B=0` or `A=0, B=1` you will have different results in `!A and !B` and `not(A and B)`.

Lets check now `not(A or B)`

```
A|B| !A | !B |[!A and !B]|  A or B |  not(A or B)
-+-+----+----+-----------+---------+---------------
0|0|  1 |  1 |    [1]    |    0    |      [1]
0|1|  1 |  0 |    [0]    |    1    |      [0]   
1|0|  0 |  1 |    [0]    |    1    |      [0]   
1|1|  0 |  0 |    [0]    |    1    |      [0]
```

Now you can see why `!A **AND** !B` can be replaced with `not(A **OR** B)`

Comment: much more useful demonstration of truth tables than @NPEs answer, IMHO

Answer (score 0):

`while(!s1.isEmpty() && !s2.isEmpty())`
and
`while(!(s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty()))`
Are equal.

//notice the "||"

VERY IMPORTANT
although the Morgan rules show that logically those two statements are the same. most languages only valuate what they have. so if the any part of the condition have side effect or can only be accessed in case of other part validity you should consider the order of the parts.

Comment: ohh now I understood but why?

Comment: @NitzanBatat - just look at the `true` table in NPE answer.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel actually, I checked it again - in both cases if `s1.isEmpty()` then the logical test will get short circuited and `s2.isEmpty()` never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

```
NOT
1 -> 0    
0 -> 1
```

Let say `s1.isEmpty()` is `True` and `s2.isEmpty()` is `False`

For **Case 1:**

`while(!s1.isEmpty() && !s2.isEmpty())`.

Then it will treat like `(False AND True)`, which finally return `False`. Because, `AND` operation of `True` and `False` is `True`.

For **Case 2:**

`while(!(s1.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()))`.

Then it will treat like `(!(True AND False))`, which return `(!(False))` and `Not` operation of `False` will be `True`.